# How to use \shortstack together with \arraystretch to achieve the same row separation?

Tags: tables, booktabs

When I use `\shortstack` to create newline in a table cell, the row separation is not the same as defined by the value of `\arraystretch`. The following MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How I can make the row separation of `\shortstack` the same as the table defined by `\arraystretch`? Or how can I control the row separation of `\shortstack`?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use a nested `tabular`? Or, redefine `\shortstack` to suit your needs?

Comment: `\shortstack` is very primitive and doesn't take into account proper line spacing. I wish it had been defined *very* differently. Better not using it.

Comment: Yes, nested `tabular` environment is definitely worked, but it seems the code is a little bit unclear, so wondering if it is ok to use `\shortstack` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stackengine` package has a `\Shortstack` macro which has a settable gap setting.  Since the `\shortstack` gap is 3pt, I here set it to 9pt for `\Shortstack`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \Shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \Shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \Shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If that is not the spacing you want, there is also the `\addstackgap` macro that adds the stacking gap above and below the argument (in this case the `\Shortstack`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{9pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \addstackgap{\Shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) }} \\ \midrule
Mg & \addstackgap{\Shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090}} \\
Al & \Shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I want, to control the row spacing from `\shortstack` in a fair simple way. Thanks for bringing out the package `stackengine` which I do not know it before.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Don't redefine kernel/core macros, since you don't know where they're used elsewhere (in the kernel, or other packages).</sub>

It seems fairly trivial to redefine `\shortstack` into something more relevant to suit your needs, and is not used in any of the base classes ([`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) or [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{siunitx,booktabs}

\renewcommand{\shortstack}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}#1@{}}% [c]enter; [t]op; [b]ottom
    #2
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\
  \midrule
  Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
  Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\
  \midrule
  Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
  Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering what the difference is by defining a new macro which contains the nested `tabular` environment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach from my other answer.  If you want to change the actual definition of `\shortstack`, here is how it can be done.  I have two new macros, `\shortstackgap{}` and `\restoreshortstack`.  The first one takes a number argument, which is used (as a point value) to redefine the `\shortstack` gap.  The second macro redefines `\shortstack` to its default definition, which has a 3pt stacking gap.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\shortstackgap[1]{%
\gdef\@shortstack[##1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox\bgroup
    \baselineskip-\p@\lineskip #1\p@
    \let\mb@l\hss\let\mb@r\hss
    \expandafter\let\csname mb@##1\endcsname\relax
    \let\\\@stackcr
    \@ishortstack}
\gdef\@ishortstack##1{\ialign{\mb@l {####}\unskip\mb@r\cr ##1\crcr}\egroup}
}
\newcommand\restoreshortstack{%
\gdef\@shortstack[##1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox\bgroup
    \baselineskip-\p@\lineskip 3\p@
    \let\mb@l\hss\let\mb@r\hss
    \expandafter\let\csname mb@##1\endcsname\relax
    \let\\\@stackcr
    \@ishortstack}
\gdef\@ishortstack##1{\ialign{\mb@l {####}\unskip\mb@r\cr ##1\crcr}\egroup}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\shortstackgap{9}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip

\restoreshortstack
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
Metal & \shortstack{Temperature \\ m.p.(\si{\celsius}) \\ b.p(\si{\celsius}) } \\ \midrule
Mg & \shortstack[c]{650 \\ 1090} \\
Al & \shortstack[c]{660 \\ 2467} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]